# How to deep copy a weight matrix within custom layer of Keras. I'm trying to store old weight matrixes for reassignment at a later point

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm attempting to reassigning the weights of a neuron to the weights it has in a previous epoch. In order to do this, I'm trying to save old weights but I'm having trouble making copies of the matrices.

I don't know how to copy an eager tensor within a custom layer. I tried using tf.identity and the copy library but both gave me errors although it is definitely possible I didn't implement it correctly. Any advice would be appreciated. I attached one of the errors below which says it should work if eager execution is on which confused me since I'm using tensorflow 2 and eager execution should be on by default.

```
class RevertWeightMatrixDenseLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, units, prob, **kwargs):
    super(RevertWeightMatrixDenseLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.units = units
    self.prob = prob


def build(self, input_shape):
    self.w = self.add_weight(
        shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
        initializer="random_normal",
        trainable=True,
    )
    self.b = self.add_weight(
        shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
    )

    self.last_weight_1 = self.w
    self.last_weight_2 = self.w

def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    current_weights = self.w
    if training:
        if self.prob > random.random():
            self.w.assign(self.last_weight_2)  # Assign preserves tf.Variable
        #deep copy all the weights here here before assignement
        self.last_weight_2 = self.last_weight_1 
        self.last_weight_1 = current_weights
    else:
        pass #could think about multiplying all weights by a constant here
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b)


model = make_base_model() #sets up a sequential model with some conv layers
model.add(ResetWeightMatrixDenseLayer(units=dense_units, prob=0.1)) #Custom layer
model.add(ResetWeightMatrixDenseLayer(units=dense_units, prob=0.1)) #Custom layer

model.add(layers.Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'CategoricalCrossentropy',
          optimizer = 'adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset, epochs=epochs)
plot(history)
```

Attempting to deepcopy where I commented leads to the following error * NotImplementedError: **deepcopy**() is only available when eager execution is enabled.*

Comment: try to use `get_weights()` / `set_weights()`. But I am not sure that it is possible to set weights in `call()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep states in your layer: that's exactly what `tf.Variable` are for. (See the guide: [Introduction to Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable))

Set your `last_weights` as a non trainable `tf.Variable`, and use assign to copy the values around.

```py
class RevertWeightMatrixDenseLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, prob, **kwargs):
        super(RevertWeightMatrixDenseLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.prob = prob


    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

        self.last_weight_1 = tf.Variable(self.w, trainable=False)
        self.last_weight_2 = tf.Variable(self.w, trainable=False)
        # we need an extra Variable to store the original value of w
        # when shuffling around
        self.tmp = tf.Variable(self.w, trainable=False)

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        self.tmp.assign(self.w)
        if training:
            if self.prob > random.random():
                self.w.assign(self.last_weight_2)  # Assign preserves tf.Variable
            self.last_weight_2.assign(self.last_weight_1)
            self.last_weight_1.assign(self.tmp)
        else:
            pass #could think about multiplying all weights by a constant here
        return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b)
```